# Is Flurrie from Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door of the species known as Ty-Foo?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey, paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

Is Flurrie from *Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door* of the species known as Ty-Foo?

I have attached some comparison pictures:

Flurrie:
[image: Flurrie]
<sub>(source: [mariowiki.com](https://www.mariowiki.com/images/5/56/Flurrie2.jpg))</sub>

Ty-Foo:

[image: Ty-Foo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official information either way, and all we have for clues are two bits (from [here](https://www.mariowiki.com/Flurrie)) that somewhat contradict each other:

- Punio says the Puni Elder calls Flurrie a "wind spirit", which is indistinct but does imply something less than a cloud.
- Flurrie's Japanese name is Clouda (クラウダ), and some (but not all) other languages use cloud-derived names.

MarioWiki currently does not place Flurrie in the "clouds" category, so it appears the prevailing opinion amongst its editors is that she's not a cloud, and therefore not a Ty-Foo (or a Foo). But again, there's nothing definitive for either claim.